# Problem with the onclick javascript for this button or link was encountered unexpected token

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-button, custom-link, detail-page

I am getting an "invalid or unexpected token" error in the javascript code below. This code is part of a Detail page button.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js")} 

var dealObj = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Name, Deal_Status__c, RecordType.Name FROM bDeal__c WHERE Id = '{! bDeal__c.Id }'"); 

var lstDeal = dealObj.getArray("records"); 

if (lstDeal.length == 0) { 
    alert('Deal not found'); 
} else { 
    if (lstDeal[0].Deal_Status__c == 'Active') { 
        var qr = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Name FROM Early_Termination__c WHERE Deal_ID__c = '{! bDeal__c.Id }' "); 
        var lstET = qr.getArray("records"); 

        if (lstET.length == 0) { 
            var dealrt = lstDeal[0].RecordType.Name; 

            if (dealrt == 'Alliance (R/O)' || dealrt == 'Segment (R/O)' || dealrt == 'CBA (R/O)' || dealrt == 'Maestro/Cirrus (R/O)') { 
                var txt; 
                var r = confirm('{!$Label.ET_Prompt_Create_Record}'); 
                if (r == true) { 
                    var et = new sforce.SObject("Early_Termination__c"); 
                    et.Deal_ID__c = '{! bDeal__c.Id }'; 
                    et.Date_Created__c = new Date(); 
                    et.Status__c = 'In Development'; 
                    var dmlResult = sforce.connection.create([et]); 

                    if (dmlResult[0].getBoolean("success")) { 
                        window.location.href = dmlResult[0].id; 

                    } else { 
                        alert(dmlResult); 
                    } 
                } else { 

                } 
            } else { 
                alert('{!$Label.ET_Error_Not_Allow_Terminate}'); 
            } 
        } else { 
            window.location.href = lstET[0].Id; 
        } 
    } else { 
        alert('{!$Label.BD_Deal_Status_Not_Active}'); 
    } 
}
```

Could anyone please help me find the issue?

Comment: What's the error you're getting? (What unexpected token?)

Comment: Hi.. Shane, error is "invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: do you know what lines it's erroring on?  If not, use console.log or alert statements to find out where your code makes it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your code doesn't have any obvious syntax errors, I suspect it's one of your Custom Labels havng a `'` in it, causing the syntax error. Always encode your merge fields when they may have JavaScript special characters:

```
var r = confirm('{!JSENCODE($Label.ET_Prompt_Create_Record)}');
```

...

```
alert('{!JSENCODE($Label.ET_Error_Not_Allow_Terminate)}');
```

...

```
alert('{!JSENCODE($Label.BD_Deal_Status_Not_Active)}');
```

---

You may want to clean up the indentation and remove the empty else block. It'd also be possible to combine the two queries to make the code shorter. You could also reduce the complexity of the code by using return statements to reduce the indentation necessary.

Comment: Oh, wow -- you're right! The missing indentation made it look like there was an extra else block (besides the empty one).  I'm going to edit the question to make it easier to read, and delete my answer!

Comment: Thank You sfdcfox. You are correct. There is an issue with the custom labels. (ET_Prompt_Create_Record )var r = confirm('{!JSENCODE($Label.ET_Prompt_Create_Record)}');  is working fine. Thank You so much

Comment: @Jury Always glad to help!